# Do not close the application after a crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, robotium

So I would like to know if it is possible to not close the application after a crash.
I am doing testing on Android applications and I would like the code that would allow me to continue my test when there is a crash

Comment: What kind of crash is it? Is there an exception that you can catch instead?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the crash. Everything I can think of you can catch an exception, log it, and keep going.

Comment: In regular Java, you can set the default exception handler. I don't know about Android. You may have to put a catch in every top level method.

Answer (score 0):

The app (usually just the top Activity) can't continue after a crash.

The best you can do is use the standard Java try/catch blocks.

Comment: my problem is that during my test case, if a crash occurs, I want to move forward and continue my test.

Comment: After a crash, would your system be stable? Could you trust any results after the crash? if you could, then the exception should probably be caught and dealt with?

Answer (score 0):

You can recover from a crash using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. Just replace the default handler with yours (using that method) and do what you want.